# set json as a payload and send username , password as a basic authentication in java

Tags: java, json, basic-authentication, restful-authentication, payload

I want to call a restful web service in java, also I want to send content-type and (username + password as a basic authentication in header. I set all the things in my code as below :

```
public class restClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String payload="{\"username\":myuser,\"password\":\"mypass\",\"nationalCode\":\"1234567890\"}";
    String requestUrl="http://192.168.1.1/myService/GetCoverage";
    sendPostRequest(requestUrl, payload);
}

public static String sendPostRequest(String requestUrl, String payload) throws Exception {

        String name = "admin";
        String password = "admin";

        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);



        URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        writer.write(payload);
        writer.close();


    System.out.println("------------> " + connection.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonString.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
        connection.disconnect();
    return jsonString.toString();
}
```

Although I've been added all the parameters but I could not get response and I see these errors in my intelij IDEA console :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://10.0.233.254/vezaratkar/GetCoverage
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
at com.mkyong.restClient.sendPostRequest(restClient.java:50)
at com.mkyong.restClient.main(restClient.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Well, it's a server-side error.

Comment: Yep, we'd need to see the server logs to see what the actual issue is.

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker , Actually I don't have access to the server logs, it's a service that I've been got it from an external company? What shall I do?

Comment: @Evan Knowles , Actually I don't have access to the server logs, it's a service that I've been got it from an external company? What shall I do?

Comment: @brelian, Try invoking the same service with the help of PostMan or Advance Rest Client. There you would be able to see the error response code and.. may be, may be.. description also.  Give it a try. If that also says "Internal Server Error", then you are out of luck !